# Порядок переменных в памяти

Tags: c, память, компилятор, стек

Влияет ли порядок объявления переменных в коде на то, в каком порядке и где им выделяет память компилятор?
Например, у меня **password_buffer** и **auth_flag** не меняют своё местоположение, если я изменю их положение в коде:

1 вариант

```
int check_authentication(char *password) {
    char password_buffer[16];
    int auth_flag = 0;

    strcpy(password_buffer, password);

    if (strcmp(password_buffer, "brilling") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;
    if (strcmp(password_buffer, "outgrade") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;

    return auth_flag;
}
```

2 вариант

```
int check_authentication(char *password) {
    int auth_flag = 0;
    char password_buffer[16];

    strcpy(password_buffer, password);

    if (strcmp(password_buffer, "brilling") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;
    if (strcmp(password_buffer, "outgrade") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;

    return auth_flag;
}
```

Comment: Как компилятор решит - так и будет :) -- стандартом это не оговорено...

Comment: Но у меня в книге сказано, что поменяв их местами, они изменят своё положение в памяти. В качестве доказательства в ней приведёт листинг из отладчика gdb

Comment: Значит книга для другого компилятора писалась. Или для других переменных, глобальных, например. А по тому коду который тут компилятор может вообще под auth_flag память не выделять, а сразу return нужный делать или в регистре ее держать

Answer (score 2):

Локальные переменные по умолчанию имеют автоматический класс хранения. Т.е.

```
auto int auth_flag = 0;
```

для вашего кода компилятор `gcc` решил, что правильнее хранить эту переменную в регистрах, то-есть  так :

```
register int auth_flag = 0;
```

А массивы в Си всегда должны храниться в памяти, то есть в стеке. И компилятор отнял у регистра `SP` (*Stack Pointer*) 16 байт.

Дальше переменные с плавающей запятой компилятору удобнее хранить в математических регистрах процессора. А их у него очень много. И у них нет адреса вообще, только имя.

При входе в функцию для тех переменных, которым компилятор решил выделить место в стеке он им выделяет **один** раз память для **всех**. А вопрос, кто выше/ниже не имеет ответа, это не имеет значения.

Пример, где порядок имеет значение, это объявление структуры. Так как это **тип**, у него должно быть фиксированное место элементов и в том порядке, что и расписано.